# Transfer all ReSharper Settings between PCs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, stylecop

I was wondering if there is a way to copy ALL my settings from ReSharper (including the StyleCop for ReSharper settings and the keyboard bindings I have set for ReSharper) from one PC to another?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Since the export option within Resharper is only for code styles, you'll need to be a bit craftier for *all* settings.

From [Peter Ritchie's blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2008/05/19/resharper-4-0-eap-settings-and-installing-latest-build.aspx)...

> ...the settings are stored in
>   "%userprofile%\application
>   data\jetbrains\resharper\v4.0\vs9.0". 
>   There are a couple of xml files in
>   there that store your settings. 
>   Before you upgrade to the latest
>   build, just copy those to another
>   directory.
>
> It's very likely that the format of
>   these files has changed since the last
>   build so copying the backups over the
>   new version could possibly make
>   Resharper to blow-up.  So, use with
>   caution.

I have Resharper 4.1 so instead of "...\v4.0\vs9.0" it's actually "...\v4.1\vs9.0" (obvious, I know, but worth mentioning).

I'm not sure about StyleCop settings, but this should work for most other settings (keyboard scheme, code completion settings, etc...).

Comment: Yeah, if moving between versions, best to do a diff on the fresh XML file and your source settings file. I'm actually about to move settings from 4.5 on my desktop to 5.0 on my laptop.

Comment: Different path on Windows 7: %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\ReSharper\<version>\vs9.0

Comment: Just an update for Resharper Ultimate 2018 I've found the settings folder in `C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\JetBrains\ReSharper\vAny`.

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan That's not where global Resharper's settings are. Here's the screen what we have there: https://i.imgur.com/ESFDKJU.png . Even after you go into the vs16.0_7f0ed8f7 or your appropriate Visual Studio version folder, there's only vsActionManager.DotSettings file: https://i.imgur.com/VWocznT.png . That's not settings. Just change your Resharper settings and see if that file is modified. It won't be. The global Resharper settings are in `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\Shared\vAny`: https://i.imgur.com/OaVFXPH.png .

Answer (score 9):

There is a [R# settings manager](http://rsm.codeplex.com/) plugin for resharper that stores all of this I think, including stylecop settings

Comment: The future of RSM is a little unclear given the new settings engine in R# 6.1: http://rsm.codeplex.com/discussions/262161

Answer (score 5):

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Go to Resharper > Manage Options
3. Click on Import and Export

[image: Import and Export]

4. Click on Export to File
5. Tick all check box

[image]

6. Click on OK and save the file to your desired location
7. To import the settings to other computer, repeat steps 1-3 and then select Import from File. You are done.

Enjoy!

Comment: This does not store all the settings. Only some.

Answer (score 3):

You can Export/Import your ReSharper Code Style or put it on the network and share between multiple computers.  To do so:

From VS Menu select ReSharper -> Options then in Option dialog select Languages/Common/Code Style Sharing.

Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, i had that in my original post but someone edited it out.

Comment: Exactly what is going to be exported? All languages section?

Answer (score 2):

StyleCop settings are not stored in the resharper plugin. they are in the stylecop directory and in an xml file (Settings.StyleCop).

Comment: Stylecop for resharper* there is a difference

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution that i am using!

Skydrive and junction link magic.
I create a junction in the filesystem that point the settings to a skydrive folder.
this way i have everywhere i use skydrive the same settings!!!

On the target pc i do the opposite.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Steve Dignan's answer is probably correct for 2009 version of Resharper.

In newer versions of Resharper global for PC Resharper settings are located in:
`%userprofile%\Appdata\Roaming\JetBrains\Shared\vAny\GlobalSettingsStorage.DotSettings`.

Solution team-shared settings are in the solution folder called `{Solution Name}.sln.DotSettings`.

Solution's personal settings are in `{Solution Name}.sln.DotSettings.user`.

Source: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001216530-Where-to-find-DotSettings-files-associated-with-settings-layers

So to transfer settings between 2 PCs, copy settings file(s) for the appropriate layer(s) you want to transfer and that's it. Usually just copying global is enough.