# Export and import resharper 6.0 settings

Tags: export, settings, resharper, resharper-6.0

I've recently installed resharper 6.0. It took my long time to set up everything as I wanted. Now I want to export all this settings to another computer. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2178408/310276) aproach without any success (might be because the computers use different versions of visual studio?). Then I found [this](http://rsm.codeplex.com/) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3019650/310276). But RSM works for r# 5. I started reading to see if there is going to be RSM for r# 6.0 and there will not be because in r# 6.1 some settings management options are included. But I'm stick with r# 6.0.. Is there any way I can transfer my settings from one PC to another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you may want to update to ReSharper 6.1 where the management of settings are [improved](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/whatsnew/index.html#settings) including an export and import feature.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't explain what you meant by "without any success".

- Were you able to find the folders and copy the files?
- Were there files already in the target directory? (If there weren't, you probably had the wrong directory.)
- Did you diff the old and new files as a sanity check? (This would be especially important since you're apparently expecting this to work even when the two machines aren't running the same version of Visual Studio. There could easily be differences in the file format across VS versions.)
- Did you make sure to close Visual Studio before copying the files?
- Did you just copy files in ReSharperVersion\VisualStudioVersion, or did you also copy the files in the vAny directory?

At any rate, if you really can't copy the global settings files, and if you can't install 6.1 (why not? it's a free upgrade from 6.0), I think your only other option is to export and import your coding-style settings by going to ReSharper > Options > Languages > Common > Code Style Sharing. That won't get *all* the ReSharper settings, but it will get some of the most important ones.

Comment: I didn't compare the files before replacing, but yes, I was able to replace them, and also to vAny directory. Nothing changed, still the same settings I had before. I closed all vs before copying and even restarted the pc (I thought there might be some process still alive). What are exactly the settings that export will save?

Comment: Also, its company policy not download beta versions. That's why I can't download 6.1. Have you tried it? Does it work fine?

Comment: Code Style Export is just for code formatting settings -- how to indent, where to add spaces, etc.; it doesn't include any other R# settings. The R#6.1 nightlies work reasonably well but there are definitely some bugs; usually not showstoppers but sometimes annoying.

Comment: So if I use Code Style Export I will have all that is under "Languages", right? I think I'll opt for that way and set up the rest of the settings manually (the hardest work is under "Languages")