# copy ReSharper 8 keyboard settings from VS2012 to VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2013

I looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885443/transfer-all-resharper-settings-between-pcs) but it's quite old and I didn't find it useful for Resharper 8.
I have Macro Pad with 70 programmable keys, I customized ReSharper keys (using VS2012) to work with my macro pad (it was very long exhausting process but it was worth it). I installed VS2013 and I'm seeing that all my keyboard customizations are not exists under it. I tried to export ReSharper settings from VS2012 and import it in VS2013 but it's not working (as it seems, ReSharper doesn't support of export and import keyboard settings).
Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: What happens if you export/import VS keyboard settings? (Ie. is ReSharper just using the underlying VS mechanism for keyboard handling?)

Comment: hmm, didn't think about it, I'll give it a try and update you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

credit to @Richard

The keyboard export should be made through VS and not through ReSharper.

1. Open your source VS version
2. Press tools and select "Import and Export settings"
3. Select the first option "Export selected environment settings"
4. Make sure "keyboard" is marked (under Environment), select destination file and save it
   [image: Make sure you export keyboard settings]
5. open your destination vs version
6. Press tools and select "Import and Export settings"
7. Select the second option "Import selected environment settings"
8. Open the file you saved before, press next
9. close and open VS and that's it.

Good luck